# Shell Script - Check if a file contains a specific line/string

Tags: shell-script, centos

## my script contain :

```
#### #!/usr/bin/sh
FILE="/home/steven/.bash_profile"
STRING="export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin""

if [ -z $(grep "$STRING" "$FILE") ]; then

        echo 'the string is exist' >&2
else

        echo 'the string doesnt exist' >&2
fi
```

## and my file contain :

```
#### # .bash_profile

 # Get the aliases and functions

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then

        . ~/.bashrc
fi

#### # User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

why it always returns the is exist?

Comment: `-z` checks if the string is empty. Did you mean to use `-n`? Or just use `grep` directly: `if grep -q "$STRING" "$FILE"; then ...`

Comment: @muru
i try grep directly but failed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We should escape the `$` and `"` in the STRING variable. Otherwise, it will expand the `$PATH`

Declare it as:

```
 STRING="export PATH=\"\$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin\""
```

As commented by @muru, try as

```
if  grep -q "$STRING" "$FILE" ; then
         echo 'the string exists' ; 
else
         echo 'the string does not exist' ; 
fi
```

Since `export` is missing on line number 12 of file bashrc, it will always report that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Or use single quotes on the outside instead of double quotes. Then you don't need to escape anything as the shell treats the entire string as a literal